# Is there a way to tell when a launched GUI application has displayed its window?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a way to launch a number of GUI applications from a script so that the application windows are displayed in the same order as the applications are launched. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is something complexer than a launch script. for example an application manager, and use events (in your case "application started" event) to launch the next application and so

If you seek to to just fire up applications from console and hope they finish initializing/starting in the same order you launched them, then its not going to work, since you have no control whatsoever how long it will take to load an application.

How the applications can communicate with the application manager to tell it they are done loading is to use the many available mechanisms of [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

If on the other hand, these applications are not yours and you can't implement IPC into them, then you have to find another way to find out whether they have started before launching the next application, maybe pinging them if they offer that, or search for certain files they create upon restart, or whatever other behavior that you can detect and decide based upon it whether an application has started or not

Answer (score 3):

It seems a job for [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/), for example:

```
wait_for_window() {
  "$@" &
  local PID=$!
  while test -z "$(wmctrl -pl | awk "\$3 ~ $PID")"; do 
    sleep 1
  done
}

wait_for_window gnome-calculator
wait_for_window gnome-terminal
```

This may need some tweaking because the relation between PIDs and windows is not always trivial, but you get the idea.